# Would it be good if a function is constantly called inside app.listen() in nodejs express?

Tags: node.js, express, nodejs-server

I'm trying to set up a server for continuously monitoring the database and doing some actions related.

Here is my coding:

```
app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`The server is listening on port ${port}`);
    setInterval(() =>{
        someAction();
        console.log("100ms ago");
    }, 100);
})

function someAction(){
    //some query...
    //some action...
}
```

Is it a good practice doing like that? Or, is there any other methods if I would like to perform what I want?

Comment: Details would help, but it'd be better to hook into listening to database changes directly, instead of polling

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good practice doing like that?

If you want to start an interval timer exactly when the server has started up, then starting the timer from within the `.listen()` callback is the way to accomplish that.

> Or, is there any other methods if I would like to perform what I want?

To start the timer exactly when the server is up and running, this is the way to do it.

You don't show all the details of what the `someAction()` code does, but unless this code actually makes requests to that server, my guess is that **it doesn't really care** whether the interval timer starts only after the server is up and running or whether the interval timer starts slightly before or after that.  If that's really the case, then you could also put it at the top level like this:

```
app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`The server is listening on port ${port}`);
});

function someAction(){
    //some query...
    //some action...
}

setInterval(() =>{
    someAction();
    console.log("100ms ago");
}, 100);
```

But, this is mostly just cosmetic.  Other than the slight difference in timing of when the timer starts there's no other operating difference between the two.